# Flip 2D asymmetric animation in Unity3D

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, 2d, character

I want to flip my 2D character (asymmetric) from right to left using the animator in Unity3D

I have the sprite sheet with both left and right sprites and I did a controller with the animations facing right, now I need to flip the animations to the other side

Done:

- Sprite sheet with both animations left and right
- Animation controller with animations facing right

Goal:

- Make my character change animations facig right to facing left and viceversa

I'm aware of the code to change the local scale, but I'm not interested in changing scale, I'm looking for a way to flip the animation

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the animations changing the x/y scale from positive to negative. Why you are not interest in changing the scale? You can flip the animations with this method.

Sorry for my English and good luck.

Comment: ilke i said, i have an asymmetric characters (means it has different elements for each side) and i don't want to flip the scale